# Visual Basic P&D wizard

Tags: vb6

I am trying to create a setup package using Visual Basic 6's Package and Deploy (P&D) wizard. When I come to the part of the install location, the only available options for the install location are `AppPath`, `Program Files`, `Common Files`, `commonfilessys`, `winpath`, `winsysPath`, and `msdaopath`.

I'd rather deploy the file to `C:\Users\(user specific login)\data\`. Is it possible to do that using Visual Basic's P&D wizard.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using the free Inno Setup instead. Just thinking of the VB6 P&D Wizard from all those years ago makes me shudder. http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?vb

Comment: The PDW cannot be used to create per-user installers.  Doing that with most VB6 programs requires a reg-free COM manifest anyway, and it seems unlikely that you have one.  I recommend you avoid "Inno Setup" like the plague.  It can be used safely but it is far easier to create disasters that break other applications and can be very costly to track down.  It is hazardous by default.

Comment: This claim is ridiculous. It would be like not to use a programming language because you can combine disasters! With this logic, any tool can cause damage, even a simple BAT file. InnoSetup is a tool (installer) and just like any other tool you just need to be studied and learned.